# Why can I still access an object that has been moved?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo{
    int i = 10;
};

Foo useless_move(Foo &&f){
    return f;
}
int main() {
    Foo f = Foo();
    f.i = 100;
    Foo f1 = useless_move(std::move(f));
    std::cout << f.i;
    std::cout << f1.i;
}
```

Why can I still access f, after I have moved the value with `Foo f1 = useless_move(std::move(f));` Didn't I transfer the ownership from f to f1?

Comment: Believe it or not, move constructor is not invoked in the code you've shown. In any case, for a trivial type like `Foo`, move constructor does the exact same thing as a copy constructor. I'm not sure what you mean by "ownership" - ownership of what? There's no resource being allocated here. Do you expect the CPU to burn a hole in the memory chip where `f` resides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing `std::move` doesn't magically make a move happen; it's really badly named in that sense. All it does is give you an rvalue reference.

Moves happen when you are passing around an rvalue reference to an object with a move constructor, which is written to swap indirect resources such as containers and file handles rather than deep copying them (or failing to properly copy them at all).

In this case, you just have an `int`.
**There's no move constructor, nothing to move, and no move performed.**

And *even if there were*, the state of an object that has just been moved from is unspecified, not guaranteed to be … well, whatever it is that you were expecting instead.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo::i` is literally a part of Foo, and cannot be given away. Like your arm. Moving resources from one instance to another is only helpful for pointers to external resources that the object owns:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo{
    int* i; //pointer to external resource
    Foo() :i(new int(10)) {}
    Foo(const Foo& rhs) :i(new int(*(rhs.i))) {}
    Foo(Foo&& rhs) :i(rhs.i) noexcept {rhs.i = nullptr;}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) {int* t=new int(*(rhs.i)); delete i; i=t; return *this;}
    Foo& operator=(Foo&& rhs) noexcept {delete i; i=rhs.i; rhs.i=nullptr; return *this;}
    ~Foo() {delete i;}
};
```

Also, there's a tiny number of wierd quirks in rvalues, and you hit another:

```
Foo useless_move(Foo &&f){
    return f;
}
int main() {    
    Foo f;
    Foo f1 = useless_move(std::move(f));
}
```

You passed `f` to `std::move`, which returns an rvalue reference.  This is a reference to `f`, with the "note" that it's safe to move from.  No move has been made.  This reference is then passed to the function `useless_move`, which accepts a rvalue reference.  That is, it accepts a reference to a `Foo`, with the note that it's safe to move from.  It then assigns this reference the name `f` inside the function.  No move has been made.  Here's the wierd part: `f` *itself* is not a rvalue reference.  It's an `lvalue` reference.  The `&&` in the declaration means that's what the function *accepts*, but *inside* the function, it's treated as a `Foo&`.  So `f` is a regular reference inside the function.  So then `return f` plus a return type of `Foo` tells the function to return a `Foo` constructed from the reference `f`, which is *not* safe to move from.  So it makes a copy.  *still* no move as been made.  Finally, `Foo f1 = ...` constructs the variable `f1` from the return value.  This one (finally!) is a move (from the copy, not from the origional).  Except the compiler can detect a variable is being constructed from a temporary, and so probably elides the move, and has `Foo` construct the variable directly.  So only a theoretical move has occurred.

Comment: But `f` wasn't moved.

Comment: Your assignment ops break hilariously for self-assignment.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I was still expanding, but yes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I hadn't noticed that `f` wasn't moved until after I'd posted the first version. self-move-assignment was indeed broken, though copy-assignment was safe.  Fixed to copy-and-move

Comment: Copy and move seems like an inefficient way to move

Comment: @T.C.: yes, thanks.  VC++ only has `throw()` so it's hard to break the habit.

Answer (score 1):

`std::move()` doesn't perform a move, it is literally a cast to an rvalue-reference. There's only one move that *can* happen, and that is on the line `Foo f = Foo()` assuming optimizations don't take place. To make a move happen take your argument by value:

```
Foo useless_move(Foo f);

Foo f1 = useless_move(std::move(f));
```

Besides, moves for primitive types is a copy so your're still not going to see any difference.